# Jquery each loop + setTimeout problems with increments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/fxLcy/ - example with setTimeout

http://jsfiddle.net/fxLcy/1/ - this is the demo without setTimeout. All elements on right place, but i really need that delayed animation =/

I want to place 6 cards per row via css transition and setTimeout. The point is, that i cant use increment for my left and top parameters inside setTimeout, because this thing just summarizes all my increments and sets elements onto final place.

```
var self = $(this);
if (increment % 6 === 0 && increment !== 0) {
    topIncrement++;
    leftIncrement = 0;
};
setTimeout(function() {
    self.css({'left' : 10 + leftIncrement * (resizedWidth + 20),
    'top' : $("#controlPanel").height() + 10 + topIncrement * (resizedHeight + 20)});
}, increment * 500)
leftIncrement++;
increment++;
```

Comment: Your increments being defined outside of the each is the problem. The value is shared across all iterations, meaning all setTimeout callbacks will use the same values of increment leftIncrement and topIncrement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is the variable is being shared accross the timeouts, you want to the javascript to close on each x and y position (you want each tmeout to take a snapshot of the x/y values - javascript closure).

So taking your above code and changing the setTimeout to the following I believe did the trick (please see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxLcy/3/))

```
var valuex = 10 + leftIncrement * (resizedWidth + 20);
var valuey = $("#controlPanel").height() + 10 + topIncrement * (resizedHeight + 20)
setTimeout(function() {
    self.css({'left' : valuex,
    'top' : valuey});
}, increment * 500)
```

Comment: You're welcome =] Glad to have been of assistance... setTimeouts in javascript can be a real pain sometimes haha.